# Investigating PostGIS table not showing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I created a table in Postgres:

```
create table eric_zs as
select z.id, z.name, st_multi(st_union(a.geom)) as geom, count(*)
from geo_as a
     inner join geo_zs z on a."ZS_id" = z.id
group by z.id, z.name;
```

That table is showing fine in QGIS.

Now, if I replace the `st_multi(st_union())` with for example `ST_Collect(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom))`, the table just won't show up in QGIS.

My question is about how I should go about investigating this kind of issue. Is there a log, a specific condition to check to get a clue about why it is not showing up ?

Comment: as a quick first check try `ST_Text(ST_Collect(...))`, and read the docs to each function and it´s possible return values carefully; QGIS won´t display e.g. `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`s. Or `NULL` for that matter...

Comment: I tried a `select * from geometry_columns` but it shows `GEOMETRY` for both.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, @ThingumaBob, it's `st_astext()` but it showed that I had a bunch of LINE rather than shapes. Please put it as an answer because it's probably the best advice.

Comment: not yet: with `ST_ExteriorRing`, *LineString*s are to be expected! but I somehow doubt that is what you got there...`ST_Collect` can return *Multi** geometries and/or *GeometryCollection*s, and QGIS doesn´t display the latter! I suspect that to be the case here.

Comment: btw.: `ST_AsText` is good for a sneak preview of your geometries in readable format; if that's not enough, there are plenty of options, e.g. `ST_IsValid`/`ST_IsValidReason`, `GeometryType`...it´s crucial to know your data and know what which function will do to it.

Comment: My question was really more general as to how one can investigate this kind of issue. I was trying to merge shapes of areas that had imperfect inner junctions (because of rivers and such) so `st_multi(st_union())` had inner lines. I found that `ST_ExteriorRing(st_union(a.geom))` was seen by QGIS and gave me the proper contour of my zones. I just need to turn it into shapes rather than lines but at least, I can see what kind of geometry is generated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79491/discussion-between-thingumabob-and-eric-darchis).